# value of largest probability base on normal approximation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be the number of heads and $X \sim Binomial(87,0.5)$. Also, let $Y$ be the number of heads. $Y \sim Normal(np,npq)$ with $np =43.5, npq=21.75$, but I don't really know the way to find the number of heads which have the largest probability based on the Normal approximation in part d?

Suppose we flip a coin $87$ times. Assume that the coin is fair.

a) Compute the probability of obtaining $53$ heads.

b) Verify if the Rule of Five is satisfied? Compute the probability of obtaining $53$ heads based on Normal approximation. Is the answer close to part a)?

c) Compute the probability of obtaining at least $53$ heads based on the Normal approximation.

d) Find the number of heads which have the largest probability based on the Normal approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

$$\mathbb{P}[X=53]=\binom{87}{53}\frac{1}{2^{87}}\approx 1.079\%$$

b)

$$\mathbb{P}[52.5<Y<53.5]=\Phi\left(\frac{53.5-43.5}{\sqrt{21.75}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{52.5-43.5}{\sqrt{21.75}}\right)\approx 1.081\%$$

c)

$$\mathbb{P}[Y\geq 53]=1-\Phi\left(\frac{52.5-43.5}{\sqrt{21.75}}\right)\approx 2.682\%$$

d) as already noted, normal distribution is symmetric around its mean thus 43 or 44 have the same largest probability

Answer (score 1):

Hint : a normal distribution attains its maximum at the mean $\mu$ and the normal distribution is simmetric to the mean, increasing when $x < \mu$  and decreasing when $x > \mu$. What can you do, then, to find the largest probability?